Правила постановки дефиса между существительными
Объясните, пожалуйста, какой логике надо следовать, выбирая, поставить ли дефис между двумя существительными.
Возьмём такой пример: Mercedes S-класса. Я интуитивно понимаю, что после буквы S нужен дефис – наверное, потому, что слово класс поясняет то, что значит S. С другой стороны, от перестановки этих двух слов дефис пропадает: Mercedes класса S. Тут я более-менее понимаю, почему так.
Но что делать со словами, в которых, как мне кажется, оба слова примерно одинаковые и никакое слово другое не поясняет. Например, кресло-качалка. Что будет, если поменять слова местами? Качалка-кресло или качалка кресло? Или, может, вообще качалка «кресло»?
Как действовать в таких случаях? Помогите, пожалуйста.


Аббревиатура “S” обозначает Sonderklasse, что в переводе — “особый класс”.

Здесь родо-видовые отношения: класс и его название S. Тогда при прямом порядке слов (род + вид) раздельное написание класс S, а при обратном (вид + род) дефисное: S-класс.
Сравнить: трава полынь и полынь-трава.

Кресло-качалка — это сложное слово, в котором нужно определить отношения между существительными.  При такой записи имеется в виду кресло с функцией качалки, то есть качалка является приложением. Родо-видовых отношений здесь нет, но отношения подчинительные. Разница в том, что раздельное письмо в этой теме не применяется, но на втором месте должно стоять именно приложение.

Попробуем изменить позицию: качалка-кресло. На практике такое не встретишь, но теоретически это означает качалка в форме кресла.
Интересны другие примеры, где перестановка возможна, например: (1) француз-гувернер — француз, который является гувернером; (2) гувернер-француз — гувернер, который по происхождению француз.

Кстати однородные сочинительные отношения можно видеть в сочетаниях друзья-приятели, вопросы-ответы. Там отношения между словами равноправные.

